# Query and Stored Procedure return different results

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am using MySQL and MySQL workbench. Can somebody please help me out here because I am losing my mind!

I run the query as follows:

```
# Retrieve user_team from user
SELECT CS_USER_TEAMS_ID
FROM classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteam 
WHERE user_id = 2;
```

Which works fine.. I get the value of `CS_USER_TEAMS_ID` which is  **2**:

[image: ss_query]

However when I create the Stored Procedure of the same query with an input parameter..

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(IN user_id INT)
BEGIN

    # Retrieve user team from user_id
    SELECT CS_USER_TEAMS_ID
    FROM classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteam 
    WHERE user_id = @user_id;

END
```

.. it returns nothing (**null**)

[image: SS_StoredProcedure]

Can somebody explain how stupid I'm being here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`(IN p_user_id INT)
BEGIN
    # Retrieve user team from user_id
    SELECT CS_USER_TEAMS_ID
    FROM classicseasonmodel_classicseasonuserteam 
    WHERE user_id = p_user_id;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and routine parameters [13.1.15. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html), are different variables.